# Make a form/div editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, edit

Hello I have around 6 fields which are read only presently. I now would have to make them editable. So I am thinking of having one image/button, which onclick would trigger the edit functionality. So onclick of that button, I would have a form load up which would have the textboxes, which makes those fields editable. I am trying to do this with JQuery, I am unable to understand on how to get a editable form out of read only fields.

How is it possible to load up a form which would have same fields as the one we had earlier and allows the users to edit?

This is my present code, I would have to load my editable form into the id.

```
<div id="student-infomercial">
<ul>
<label>Name:</label>
<div ><?php echo $name; ?></div>
</li>
<li>
<label>Age:</label>
<div ><?php echo $age; ?></div>
</li>
<li>
<label>Country:</label>
<div ><?php echo $country; ?></div>
</li>
<li>
<label>State:</label>
<div ><?php echo $state; ?></div>
</li>
<li>
<label>City:</label>
<div ><?php echo $city; ?></div>
</li>
<li>
<li>
<label>Zip:</label>
<div ><?php echo $zip; ?></div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How are they readonly? Are you using the readonly attribute of HTML's input?

Comment: no right now! I have them displayed in list items

Comment: what about HTML5 editable attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess you're asking how to transform your  element into ? You can do it, but it probably will be too much trouble. If I were you I would have following html instead:

```
<div id="student-infomercial">
<ul>
<label>Name:</label>
<input class="disabled" disable="true"><?php echo $name; ?></input>
</li>
<li>
<label>Age:</label>
<input class="disabled" disabled="true"><?php echo $age; ?></input>
</li>
</div>
```

then in your javascript:

```
$("#buttonId").bind("click", function(){
   var fields = $(".disabled");
    fields.removeClass("disabled");
    fields.addClass("enabled");
    fields.removeAttr("disabled", "");
});
```

If you insist on using `<div>` then you will have to transform the `<div>` tags to `<input>` tags upon some event.

There are many many more ways you can achieve your goal; the above is just the solution that pops into my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Start using https://github.com/tectual/jQuery-Editable. it has a **data-for** attribute.

Basically you define the display div/label with **data-for** attribute for a field and then calling **$('formCssSelector').editables()** will make them all editable. and setting **onFreeze** function you can define to use your preferred validation system and if all fields are valid submit using **$.ajax**

sample page for [jquery editable html 5 technique](http://www.tectual.com.au/downloads/jquery/editable/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)?  I think it will work well for what you want.

EDIT to address comment.

Here is a starting point

```
$("li").each(function () {
  var text = $(this).text();
  var $input = $("<input>");
  $input.attr("type", "text");
  $input.attr("value", text);
  $(this).html($input);
});
```

Comment: I want all the fields to be editable at a single click and not one click per input element

Answer (score 0):

Are you just asking how to unset the disabled attribute?

```
$("#myform input").attr("disabled", "");
```

Comment: No, I am trying to find a way if I can load up a form, which would allow the users to edit the existing values.

Answer (score 0):

So another option is to create an entirely separate page with the editable form. Say form.php with code like this:

```
  <form action="whatever.php" method="POST">
     <ul><li>
       <label>Name:</label>
       <input type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/>
       </li>
       <li>
         <label>Age:</label>
         <input type="text" value="<?php echo $age; ?>"/>
       </li>
       etc 
 </form>
```

Then on your display page you can add a button named edit and load the form using AJAX like this:

```
   $("#editButton").click(function(){
       $("#student-infomercial").load("form.php");
   });
```

This way the entire display is replaced with a form. You can then add a cancel button on the form to go back to the display.